# sklearn: chaining multiple transformers with ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How can I apply multiple transformers to a *single* pandas DataFrame column using the ColumnTransformer API?

For example, I want to take the cubic root and then standardize the values in a DataFrame column:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
  np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]]),
  columns=['a', 'b', 'c']
)
transformer = ColumnTransformer(
  [
    ('root3_std', StandardScaler() + FunctionTransformer(np.cbrt), 'a') <-- pseudocode
  ],
  remainder='passthrough'
)
```

If I write

```py
transformer = ColumnTransformer(
  [
    ('root3', FunctionTransformer(np.cbrt), 'a'),
    ('standardize', StandardScaler(), 'a')
  ],
  remainder='passthrough'
)
```

I get two separate columns, one with the cubic roots and another with the standardized original values. How can I apply **both** transformers in one go?

Comment: Try `Pipeline` from `sklearn.pipeline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame(
np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]]),
columns=['a', 'b', 'c']
)


pipe = Pipeline([('function_transformer', FunctionTransformer(np.cbrt)), 
                 ('standard_scalar', StandardScaler())])

pipe.fit_transform(df[['a']])

#op
array([[-1.32381804],
   [ 0.23106179],
   [ 1.09275626]])
```